Autowired Integration Test can't detect Component annotation
I'm writing an Integration test for creating a record and read it from database in Spring Boot. When I run the test this is the error I received:
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.914 s <<< FAILURE! -- in com.juno.databasedemo.dao.AuthorDaoImplIntegrationTest
com.juno.databasedemo.dao.AuthorDaoImplIntegrationTest.testThatAuthorCanBeCreatedAndRecalled -- Time elapsed: 0.057 s <<< ERROR!
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [com.juno.dao.impl.AuthorDaoImpl underTest] in constructor [public com.juno.databasedemo.dao.AuthorDaoImplIntegrationTest(com.juno.dao.impl.AuthorDaoImpl)]: No qualifying bean of type 'com.juno.dao.impl.AuthorDaoImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.juno.dao.impl.AuthorDaoImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1880)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:471)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.ParameterResolutionDelegate.resolveDependency(ParameterResolutionDelegate.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.resolveParameter(SpringExtension.java:342)
    ... 3 more

Here is my code:
AuthorDaoImplIntegrationTest.java
package com.juno.databasedemo.dao;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import com.juno.dao.impl.AuthorDaoImpl;
import com.juno.databasedemo.TestDataUtil;
import com.juno.domain.Author;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class AuthorDaoImplIntegrationTest {
    
    private AuthorDaoImpl underTest;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorDaoImplIntegrationTest(AuthorDaoImpl underTest) {
        this.underTest = underTest;
    }

    @Test
    void testThatAuthorCanBeCreatedAndRecalled() {
        Author author = TestDataUtil.createAuthorForTesting();

        // Test Author Creation
        underTest.create(author);

        // Test Author Recall
        Optional<Author> result = underTest.findOne(author.getId());

        // Assertion
        assertThat(result).isPresent();
        assertThat(result.get()).isEqualTo(author);
    }
}

AuthorDaoImpl.java:
package com.juno.dao.impl;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.juno.dao.AuthorDao;
import com.juno.domain.Author;

@Component
public class AuthorDaoImpl implements AuthorDao {
    
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public AuthorDaoImpl(final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void create(Author author) {
        this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO author(id, name, age) values (?, ?, ?)",
        author.getId(), author.getName(), author.getAge());
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Author> findOne(int id) {
        List<Author> results = jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT id, name, age FROM author where id = ? LIMIT = 1", 
            new AuthorRowMapper(), id);

        return results.stream().findFirst();
    }

    public static class AuthorRowMapper implements RowMapper<Author> {

        @Override
        public Author mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Author author = Author.builder()
                                .id(rs.getInt("id"))
                                .name(rs.getString("name"))
                                .age(rs.getInt("age"))
                                .build();
            
            return author;
        }
        
    }
}

DatabaseConfig.java:
package com.juno.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(final DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate restTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        return restTemplate;
    }
    
}

Please show me how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!
I have tried to create Beans for both DataSource and AuthorDaoImpl in the DatabaseConfig.java but it does not seem to solve the issue as I still receive the same error message.

You have omitted the package declarations in your posted code. I think they are relevant in this case..

I've added the package declarations. I'm terribly sorry for the inconvenient.
